# Ceiling fan wobble due to crooked threading?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I installed a ceiling fan today that wobbled. I spent about 90 minutes messing with a balancing kit and could not get the wobble to go away.

I took the fan down, put it on my flat floor and spun the motor housing with the downrod still installed. The downrod wobbled side to side as it spun around the motor and clearly was not sitting straight. Since the downrod is threaded into the motor housing though, there's not much I could do to get it straight. Just for kicks, I put the downrod back into my old ceiling fan which had no wobble and it too looked in that one too. I don't know why that one didn't appear to wobble but the new one does, although the new fan has more and longer blades.

Anyways - if the downrod isn't threaded straight into the motor housing, am I out of luck no matter what? Or is this typical?

Comment: If it's new, take it back for a replacement.

Comment: I agree, take it back for a replacement, it out of balance. There are fan balancing kits (weights), but if it’s new return defective to seller and get another.

Comment: If the down-rod is not perpendicular to the plane of the fan blades, the fan will wobble. Was the down-rod cross threaded or is the axis of the threads off perpendicular?

Comment: I suspect that the threads in either the motor housing or the 4 foot downrod are not straight, or that the motor housing is not on straight. It's a bit confusing that the downrod doesn't sit straight in my old fan either but that one didn't appear to wobble.